# Styling steps in HTML range input

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, range

I create a simple range slider. Now I want to stylize steps, to be a little circles. I also want them to assign the external value, as shown below.As you can see, I have many types of slider ... cry for help.

```
<input id="inp1" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="0">
```

This is my slider

[image]

But I want this

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<input id="inp1" type="range" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="0">
```

CSS:

```
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 3px;
    background: #bfbfbf;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
} 

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #74B643;
    margin-top: -6px; 
} 

input[type=range]:focus {
    outline: none; 
} 

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Put your HTML as reference in your question. Also don't forget mark it as source code.

Comment: http://www.jqueryrain.com/?1RE1sMzh

Comment: I saw that, but I don't manage to do what I want.

Comment: @Goran look at Example 13 & Example 14 on jqueryrain. It does exactly what you want. Or maybe even Example 21.

Answer (score 10):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".__range-step").forEach(function(ctrl) {
 var el = ctrl.querySelector('input');        
 var output = ctrl.querySelector('output'); 
 var newPoint, newPlace, offset;
 el.oninput =function(){ 
  // colorize step options
  ctrl.querySelectorAll("option").forEach(function(opt) {
   if(opt.value<=el.valueAsNumber)                
    opt.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
   else
    opt.style.backgroundColor = '#aaa';
  });           
  // colorize before and after
  var valPercent = (el.valueAsNumber  - parseInt(el.min)) / (parseInt(el.max) - parseInt(el.min));            
  var style = 'background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 0%, color-stop('+
  valPercent+', green), color-stop('+
  valPercent+', #aaa));';
  el.style = style;

  // Popup
    if((' ' + ctrl.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + '__range-step-popup' + ' ') > -1)
    {
   var selectedOpt=ctrl.querySelector('option[value="'+el.value+'"]');
   output.innerText= selectedOpt.text;
   output.style.left = "50%"; 
   output.style.left = ((selectedOpt.offsetLeft + selectedOpt.offsetWidth/2) - output.offsetWidth/2) + 'px'; 
    }           
 };
 el.oninput();    
});

window.onresize = function(){
 document.querySelectorAll(".__range").forEach(function(ctrl) {
  var el = ctrl.querySelector('input');    
  el.oninput();    
 });
};
```

```css
.__range input
{
  outline: none;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 background-color: #aaa;
 height: 3px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
.__range input::-webkit-slider-thumb
{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: -moz-grab;
 cursor: -webkit-grab; 
}            
.__range input::-moz-range-thumb
{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: -moz-grab;
 cursor: -webkit-grab; 
}
.__range input::-ms-thumb
{
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 border-radius: 50%;
 cursor: -moz-grab;
 cursor: -webkit-grab; 
}
.__range-step{
 position: relative;                
}

.__range-max{
 float: right;
}
.__range-step input::-webkit-slider-thumb
{
 background: transparent;
}            
.__range-step input::-moz-range-thumb
{
 background: transparent;
}
.__range-step input::-ms-thumb
{
 background: transparent;
}
.__range-step datalist {
 position:relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 height: auto;
 bottom: 16px;
 /* disable text selection */
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */        
 -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
 -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+/Edge */                
 user-select: none; /* Standard */
 /* disable click events */
 pointer-events:none;  
}
.__range-step datalist option {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 min-height: 10px;
 border-radius: 100px;
 /* hide text */
 white-space: nowrap;       
  padding:0;
  line-height: 40px;
}


 .__range-step-popup output 
{ 
 position: absolute;
 background-color: green;                
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px; 
 text-align: center; 
 color: white; 
 border-radius: 100px; 
 display: inline-block; 
 font-size:12px;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
 line-height: 30px;
}
.__range-step-popup .__range-output-square{
 padding: 0 5px; 
 min-width: 25px;
 width: auto !important;                
 border-radius: 5px !important;
}
.__range-step-popup output:after 
{ 
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 10px solid green;
 border-left: 10px solid transparent;
 border-right: 10px solid transparent;
 top: 90%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -10px;
 margin-top: -1px;
}
.__range-step-popup datalist{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.__range-step{
  margin:0 40px;
}
.__range-step-popup{
  margin:40px 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="__range __range-step">
        <input value="3" type="range" max="5" min="1" step="1" list="ticks1">
        <datalist id="ticks1">
          <option value="1">Now</option>
          <option value="2">1 mth</option>
          <option value="3">2 mth</option>
          <option value="4">3 mth</option>
          <option value="5">4+ mth</option>
        </datalist>
</div>


<div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
        <input value="30" type="range" max="50" min="10" step="10" list="ticks2">
        <datalist id="ticks2">
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="20">20</option>
          <option value="30">30</option>
          <option value="40">40</option>
          <option value="50">50</option>
        </datalist>
        <output ></output>
</div>

<div class="__range __range-step __range-step-popup">
        <input value="1" type="range" max="4" min="1" step="1" list="ticks2">
        <datalist id="ticks2">
          <option value="1">Very bad</option>
          <option value="2">Bad</option>
          <option value="3">Good</option>
          <option value="4">Excellent</option>  
        </datalist>
        <output class="__range-output-square"></output>
</div>
```